# IOS autolayout constrains not working as expected

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, constraints

I'm quite new to ios development.

The left one is my viewcontroller, the right one is the preview. This seems quite alright. 
[image]

Then when I run it on a emulator. This happens. I believe it's because of the constraints. I used "add missing constraints". Anyone knows where the problem could be?
[image]

My viewcontroller scene:
[image]

List of constraints: 
[image]

Comment: can you share your storyBoard?

Comment: Yes I can, 1 sec. I have only on view though

Comment: Are you sure this is the constraints? It might be that all but one of the labels are having their text set to blank. What constraints are present?

Comment: I checked for a label that I could have missed, but that's not the case. I've added a list of constraints. If you would like some other information. Don't mind asking.

Comment: I mean zip your storyboard file and upload it and share a link..:) @Manu

Comment: Sorry it took so long. I put my code on github. https://github.com/kakkarm001/mp3Experiment/tree/master/MP3Experiment/Base.lproj

Comment: Thanks Dharmesh, but I fixed it by trying over and over.

Comment: @Manu did you fix it...or need help??

Comment: I fixed it, but thanks